# Inject plugin in WizardTemplateProvider templates using IDE plugin

Tags: android, plugins, android-gradle-plugin

I am creating a template for MVVM. Which will work as a IDE template and help me to get all the boilerplate Code. I have achieved to create  ACTIVITY, ViewModel, and required Layout files.

- Now I am working on adding plugins and dependencies to the
  ***build.gradle*** file
- Adding Dependency works fine

> addDependency("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")

But

> applyPlugin("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")

produces error which is attached below. So what is the proper method of adding plugins.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.RecipeExecutor.applyPlugin(java.lang.String)'
    at other.activity.VLibraryActivityRecipeKt.VLibraryActivityRecipe(VLibraryActivityRecipe.kt:173)
    at other.activity.VLibraryActivityTemplateKt$VLibraryActivityTemplate$1$2.invoke(VLibraryActivityTemplate.kt:104)
    at other.activity.VLibraryActivityTemplateKt$VLibraryActivityTemplate$1$2.invoke(VLibraryActivityTemplate.kt)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewTemplateRendererKt$doRender$1.run(NewTemplateRenderer.kt:98)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.lambda$doRunWriteCommandAction$1(WriteCommandAction.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:947)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.lambda$doRunWriteCommandAction$2(WriteCommandAction.java:148)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:219)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:184)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.doRunWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.lambda$run$0(WriteCommandAction.java:128)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:214)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$200(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:196)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
```

This is the ***recipe executor*** Class from which i am getting ***addDependency*** and ***applyPlugin*** methods

```
package com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template

public interface RecipeExecutor {
    public abstract fun addClasspathDependency(mavenCoordinate: kotlin.String, minRev: kotlin.String? /* = compiled code */): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun addDependency(mavenCoordinate: kotlin.String, configuration: kotlin.String /* = compiled code */, minRev: kotlin.String? /* = compiled code */, moduleDir: java.io.File? /* = compiled code */, toBase: kotlin.Boolean /* = compiled code */): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun addDynamicFeature(name: kotlin.String, toModule: java.io.File): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun addIncludeToSettings(moduleName: kotlin.String): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun addModuleDependency(configuration: kotlin.String, moduleName: kotlin.String, toModule: java.io.File): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun addSourceSet(type: com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.SourceSetType, name: kotlin.String, dir: java.io.File): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun applyPlugin(plugin: kotlin.String): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun copy(from: java.io.File, to: java.io.File): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun createDirectory(at: java.io.File): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun getClasspathDependencyVarName(mavenCoordinate: kotlin.String, valueIfNotFound: kotlin.String): kotlin.String

    public abstract fun getDependencyVarName(mavenCoordinate: kotlin.String, valueIfNotFound: kotlin.String): kotlin.String

    public abstract fun hasDependency(mavenCoordinate: kotlin.String, moduleDir: java.io.File? /* = compiled code */): kotlin.Boolean

    public abstract fun mergeXml(source: kotlin.String, to: java.io.File): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun open(file: java.io.File): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun requireJavaVersion(version: kotlin.String, kotlinSupport: kotlin.Boolean /* = compiled code */): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun save(source: kotlin.String, to: java.io.File): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun setBuildFeature(name: kotlin.String, value: kotlin.Boolean): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun setComposeOptions(kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion: kotlin.String?, kotlinCompilerVersion: kotlin.String?): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun setCppOptions(cppFlags: kotlin.String, cppPath: kotlin.String, cppVersion: kotlin.String): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun setExtVar(name: kotlin.String, value: kotlin.String): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun setUseKotlinIrCompiler(): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun setViewBinding(value: kotlin.Boolean): kotlin.Unit
}
```

> And this is my LibraryActivityRecipe.kt

```
package other.activity

import android.databinding.tool.ext.toCamelCase
import com.android.tools.idea.npw.module.recipes.addKotlinPlugins
import com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.Language
import com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.ModuleTemplateData
import com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.RecipeExecutor
import com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.escapeKotlinIdentifier
import com.android.tools.idea.wizard.template.impl.other.automotiveMediaService.buildGradle
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.merge
import other.utlis.*
import java.io.File
import kotlin.script.experimental.api.merge



fun RecipeExecutor.LibraryActivityRecipe(
    moduleData: ModuleTemplateData,
    className: String,
    layoutName: String,
    title: String,
    packageName: String,
    isViewMode: Boolean,
    isResourcePrefix: Boolean,
    headerString: String,
    resourcePrefixName: String
) {

    val (projectData, srcOut, resOut, manifestOut) = moduleData

    val appCompatVersion = moduleData.apis.appCompatVersion
 
    val ktOrJavaExt = projectData.language.extension
    var applicationPackage = projectData.applicationPackage//包名

    if (applicationPackage.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        applicationPackage = escapeKotlinIdentifier(packageName)
    }


   
    var resourcePrefixClass = getResPrefixClass(applicationPackage, resourcePrefixName, isResourcePrefix)


 
    var resourcePrefixXml = getResPrefixXml(applicationPackage, resourcePrefixName, isResourcePrefix)


  
    val pkFile = getApplicationPackageFile(srcOut, applicationPackage)



    val typeName = "Activity"

  
    val lastClassName = getFormatName(resourcePrefixClass + className)

  
    val lastClassNameFormat = getFormatName(lastClassName, typeName)

   
    val lastLayoutName = resourcePrefixXml + layoutName


    val lastItemName = lastLayoutName + "_item"


    val lastTitleName = resourcePrefixXml + "string_" + className.toLowerCase() + "_title"



    save(
   
        getStrClass(
            isViewMode,
            applicationPackage,
            packageName,
            lastClassName,
            typeName,
            lastLayoutName.toCamelCase(),

            headerString
        ),
        srcOut.resolve("$lastClassNameFormat.$ktOrJavaExt")
    )

    save(
        getStrXml(isViewMode, applicationPackage, packageName, lastClassNameFormat, lastItemName),
        resOut.resolve("layout/${lastLayoutName}.xml")
    )


    if (!title.isNullOrEmpty()) {
 
        mergeXml(getStrString(lastTitleName, title), resOut.resolve("values/strings.xml"))
    }



    if (isViewMode) {
     
        val viewModelName = getFormatName(lastClassName, "ViewModel") //MainActivityViewModel
        save(
            getStrViewModule(applicationPackage, lastClassName, headerString),
            pkFile.resolve("viewmodel/$viewModelName.$ktOrJavaExt")
        )


        save(
            getStrXmlItem(applicationPackage, lastClassName),
            resOut.resolve("layout/$lastItemName.xml")
        )

    }


    mergeXml(
        getStrAndroidManifestXml("${packageName}.${lastClassNameFormat}"),
        manifestOut.resolve("AndroidManifest.xml")
    )

    applyPlugin("kotlin-kapt")
    addDependency("com.android.support:support-media-compat:${appCompatVersion}.+")
    addDependency("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")




    open(srcOut.resolve("${lastClassNameFormat}.${ktOrJavaExt}"))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have two different opposite answer to your question.

1. The request has been submit to Google Issue Tracker site
   https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213757358 . It means there isn't any way to implement it.
2. But I have seen a sample where Hilt is integrated but I haven't tested it yet. So test it yourself.

**CustomActivity.kt**

```
fun RecipeExecutor. customActivityRecipe(
    moduleData: ModuleTemplateData,
    activityClass: String,
    isLauncher: Boolean,
    addHilt: Boolean,
    generateLayout: Boolean,
    layoutName: String,
    packageName: String
) {
    val (projectData, srcOut, resOut, manifestOut) = moduleData
    val ktOrJavaExt = projectData.language.extension
    val appCompatVersion = moduleData.apis.appCompatVersion
    val useAndroidX = projectData.androidXSupport

    addAllKotlinDependencies(moduleData) // to gradle

    mergeXml(
        source = androidManifestXml(activityClass, moduleData.isLibrary, isLauncher, packageName),
        to = manifestOut.resolve("AndroidManifest.xml")
    ) // to gradle

    if (generateLayout) {
        generateSimpleLayout(moduleData, activityClass, layoutName)
    }

    addDependency("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$appCompatVersion.+")

    if (addHilt) {
        applyPlugin("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
        applyPlugin("kotlin-kapt")
        addClasspathDependency("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28-alpha")
        addDependency("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha")
        addDependency("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha", "kapt")
    }

    val customActivity = when (projectData.language) {
        Language.Java -> customActivityJava(
            activityClass,
            generateLayout,
            layoutName,
            packageName,
            useAndroidX
        )
        Language.Kotlin -> customActivityKt(
            activityClass,
            generateLayout,
            layoutName,
            packageName,
            useAndroidX
        )
    }

    save(source = customActivity, to = srcOut.resolve("$activityClass.$ktOrJavaExt"))

    open(srcOut.resolve("$activityClass.$ktOrJavaExt"))
}
```

Reference of above code
[MVI Code Template](https://github.com/VeraUvads/mvi-setup/blob/e2209199545bbbc21ca25df25c1eedcd66638fd1/src/main/kotlin/com/github/verauvads/mvisetup/recipies/customActivity.kt)